# Convertiny Monetary Units

Tags: java, units-of-measurement

I got the dollars to work but now I can`t figure out how to display the quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies correctly. Technically they show up but my professor wants $1.35 to show up as 1 dollar 1 quarter and 1 dime. But, mine shows up as 1 dollars 5 Quarters 13 Dimes 27 Nickels 135 Pennies. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputeChange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an amount in double, for example 11.56: " );
        double number = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Your amount " + number + " consists of ");
        int remainingamount = (int)(number*100);
        int Quarters = remainingamount/25;
        int Dimes = remainingamount/10;
        int Nickels = remainingamount/5;
        int Pennies = remainingamount;

        if (number == 1) {
            System.out.print("1 dollar ");
        }
        else if (number > 1) {
            System.out.print((int)number + " dollars ");
        }
        if (number == 0) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.print(Quarters + " Quarters " + Dimes + " Dimes " + Nickels + " Nickels " + Pennies + " Pennies");
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep dividing remainder to get one of the units, but never updating the remainder means you will be getting unexpected results

Answer (score 0):

For each different coin you calculate, you need to remove this from the remaining amount. Such as (untested):

```
    int Dollars = (int)number;
    int remainingamount = (int)((number-Dollars)*100);
    int Quarters = remainingamount/25;
    remainingamount -= Quaters * 25;
    int Dimes = remainingamount/10;
    remainingamount -= Dimes * 10
    int Nickels = remainingamount/5;
    remainingamount -= Nickels * 5
    int Pennies = remainingamount;
```

Comment: I`m still struggling on how to display the correct values. I emailed a friend an they said "You are forgetting to get the reminder value after diving by the value." Can someone visually explain that?

Comment: If you have 55c, converted to quarters that is 55/25 = 2 with reminder 5. 2 quarters equals 50 cents, 5 remains. That is what I have shown when subtracting from remainingamount after each step. (My code didn't account for whole dollars, updated)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Java, have you tried JSR 354? 
See [JavaMoney.org](http://javamoney.org/) or the [JSR 354 Detail page at JCP.org](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=354) It offers standard API for the conversion of monetary units and default exchange rate providers by the IMF or European Central Bank.